# Differentiate $y = |x|(5 − x^2)^.5$

Tags: calculus

The curve:

$$y = |x|(5 − x^2)^.5$$

is called a bullet-nose curve. Find an equation of the tangent line to this curve at the point $(2, 2)$.

How would I differentiate the absolute value?

Comment: 'Near' $2$ you have $|x|=x$, so, 'near' $2$ it holds that $(x\mapsto |x|)'=(x\mapsto x)'=\bf 1$.

Comment: Just to say what Git Gud said in more general terms: the derivative is local, meaning it encodes only local information about your function. That is why you don't need to worry about the absolute value, because near 2, $|x|=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}|x|&=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}\\&=\frac{x}{|x|}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

An approach that avoids the absolute value is to square both sides and differentiate implicitly: $$\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = 2y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(|x|(5-x^2)^.5)^{2}=\frac{d}{dx}x^2 (5-x^2)$$
From there one can evaluate $dy/dx$ without much hassle.

Comment: I sketched this approach out on paper and was about to type it as an answer (with the additional observation that the product rule can easily be avoided) but then, when I scrolled to the bottom of the page to see if anyone besides alex.jordan had posted an answer, I saw your answer. Oh, well . . .